# Sequel gem + postgres performance handling large set at once vs. small set

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I have a database of roughly 3 million rows (four or five columns, integers and strings). I'm wondering what is more optimal to do:

A) use DISTINCT on a column of integers and then use `.map(:some_column)` to grab all unique values of :some_column

or

B) same as above, but use `.limit(100)` on each call, and move through each 100 rows, doing what needs to be done with each set of 100 rows.

Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how many unique values there are in the 3 million rows.  If there are only 10,000 unique values, then the `map(:some_column)` is fine.  If there are 3 million unique values, it's going to be painful.   You definitely want to avoid a limit/offset approach.  The fastest approach for a large number of unique values would probably be to use the streaming support in sequel_pg, or for even more speed drop down a level and use the ruby-pg driver directly (streaming there as well).

Comment: I’ll look into streaming support, that sounds like the best plan as it is probably +500k unique values and it’s growing rapidly